# JQuery search for combining textbox and dropdown fields using single searchbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a dropdown box for one field and a textbox search for other fields. I need to combine those searches in a single search. The code below does not combine the both searches into a single search. I need to combine the two search results and produce an output. How can I combine both searches?

```
function onSearch() {
    var q = $("#textboxsearch").val();
    var drop1;
    var drop = $("#dropdown option:selected").val() == "" ? 
        q : ($("#dropdown").val() == "True" ? true : false);

    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.query({
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        filter: {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [
                { field: "Name", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Project", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Id", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Type", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Usage", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Builder", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Status", operator: "contains", value: q },
                { field: "Group", operator: "contains", value: q },
            ],                                         
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
                { field: "IsActive", operator: "contains", value: drop }
            ]
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var drop = $("#dropdown option:selected").val() == "" ?  q : ($("#dropdown").val() == "True" ? true : false);
```

replace below above line with below

```
var drop = $("#dropdown").val();
```

Comment: I have changed that condition but for that too its not given the result as expected

Comment: It does not show me any error. The output is needed by combining the two filters but it does not gives the combination of those two.

Comment: The logic and filters are the problem i think

Comment: The code which i mentioned above only gives the result for the Dropdown values not for the textbox field search value.